# Mysql SEC_TO_TIME without trailing seconds - Solution Found

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table that stores dates in the format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

What i want is to SUM the HH:MM:SS part for the selected rows, so as i found in another post i use the query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(date))) FROM table
```

This query works. It sums the part that i want and returns it in the format HH:MM:SS.

My question is if its possible to strip of the seconds from the result.

I have to do this in the query, as the CMS that i use  doesn't allow me to use php on this part.

By the way it would be amazing if i could return the result in days, hours and minutes in case the sum is greater that 24 hours.

Thanks in advance

**For anyone interested i found the solution**

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(hours))),'%H:%i' ) FROM table
```

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: In the table i have two rows with data '2012-03-27 01:05:00' and '2012-03-27 17:00:00'. The above query returns '18:05:00' which is correct but what i want is to return '18:05'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, it will calculate days, hours and minutes -

```
SELECT
  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(date) DIV 86400) days,
  SUM(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(date) % 86400)))) hours,
  SUM(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(date) % 86400)))) minutes
FROM table
```

Then use CONCAT function to format these result into one string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works although i'm struggling to make CONCAT work.

Comment: Using time_format() on the sec_to_time may be easier, but this is still very nice

Answer (score 3):

An efficient solution is to cut the last 3 characters:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds), 1, 5);
```

Comment: it works in any case

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(1001),2,7);
```

will output

```
0:16:41
```

Comment: Not good. This strips the first digit of the hour, and leaves the seconds in.

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME(24*3600*10) = 240:00:00` would change to `40:00:0`